# ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 30, 30, 3) are incompatible despite being one hot encoded

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on a CNN but I keep running into this error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 30, 30, 3) are incompatible
```

My `y_train` and `y_test` are one hot encoded but that's having no impact.

Any advice?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
#from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

X_train = pickle.load(open("X_train.pickle","rb"))
y_train = pickle.load(open("y_train.pickle","rb"))
#y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=3)

X_test = pickle.load(open("X_test.pickle","rb"))
y_test = pickle.load(open("y_test.pickle","rb"))
#y_test = np.array(y_test)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu',input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
         epochs=2000,
         batch_size=128,
         validation_split = 0.1)
```

Comment: Notice: you have `y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=3)` instead of `y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=3)`

Comment: Also the `(None, 3)` makes sense since your network has a `Dense(3)` as last layer, so the issue is with `y_train`, what's it's shape and the nature of its content? In other words, where do the `30, 30` come from?

Comment: A quick fix might be to reshape your `(None, 3)` array into a `(None, 1, 1, 3)` array.

Comment: Probably the input shape (`X_train.shape`) is not a 2D array like (n_samples, n_features). And it has rank > 2, something like (n_samples, 30,30). So, you get other dimension in the output. If so, the model needs to add `Flatten` layer as first layer like: `model.add(Flatten(input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]))`